# memoir class table of content formatting

Tags: memoir

How can I replace Chapter 1 with Chapter One in the table of contents when using the memoir class?
I tried the following but it does not work:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4]{memoir}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage[scriptsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage[compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[left=3cm,top=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{afterpage}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother


\newif\ifendLOF

\newcommand*{\lofheader}{
\ifendLOF\else\hbox to \linewidth%
  {{~\ul{Figure}}~\hfill{\ul{Description}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}}\par%
  \vspace{12pt}%
  \afterpage{\lofheader}
\fi}%

\newif\ifendLOT

\newcommand*{\lotheader}{
\ifendLOT\else\hbox to \linewidth%
  {{~\ul{Table}}~\hfill{\ul{Description}}~\hfill{\ul{Page}}}\par%
  \vspace{12pt}%
  \afterpage{\lotheader}
\fi}%

 \renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}

\begin{document}
\DoubleSpacing
\chapterstyle{brotherton}
\renewcommand\bibname{References}
Title page goes here
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
Dedication goes here
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Acknowledgment}
Acknowledgment goes here
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\lofheader}
\endLOFtrue
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Tables}
\listoftables
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\lotheader}
\endLOTtrue
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
Abstract goes here
\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}
\chapter{Test1} 
This is the first chapter.
\section{this is section 1.1}
This is a test
\chapter{Test2} 
This is the second chapter.
\section{this is section 2.1}
This is a test
\chapter{Test3} 
This is the third chapter.
\section{this is section 3.1}
This is a test

\SingleSpacing
\setlength{\bibsep}{\baselineskip}
\newpage

\bibliography{Thesis}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `memoir` class emulates `tocloft` already. Please post a compilable document, not just fragments

Comment: Here is the File:

Comment: Please edit your question to include your example. Big code chunks in comments are pointless.

Comment: Dear Johannes_B .  I have done so

Comment: See section 9.2.2 (page 151 and 152) of memoir's manual (Memmanual.pdf) and look for the macro \NumToName{}, to express in letters the chapter's number.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[article,twocolumn,12pt]{memoir}

\renewcommand*{\cftchaptername}{Chapter\space}% p. 151, memmanual
\renewcommand*{\chapternumberline}[1]{%
\cftchaptername\protect\NumToName{#1}\space--\space}% p. 152, memmanual

\title{Document Title}
\author{First Name and Surname}
\date{\today}

\renewcommand{\maketitlehookd}[1]{\tableofcontents*}
% Show the toc in one-column after the date.

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Capítulo primero}
xx\dotfill xx

\section{Sección 1.1}
xx\dotfill xx

\subsection{Sub--sección 1.1.1}
xx\dotfill xx

\subsubsection{Sub--sub--sección 1.1.1.1}
xx\dotfill xx

\chapter{Capítulo segundo}
xx\dotfill xx

\section{Sección 2.1}
xx\dotfill xx

\subsection{Sub--sección 2.1.1}
xx\dotfill xx

\subsubsection{Sub--sub--sección 2.1.1.1}
xx\dotfill xx

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works. Many thanks. I really appreciate it

Comment: @khaleel Can you mark this answer as accepted by you. The help stats: "When a user receives a good answer to his or her question, 
that user has the option to "accept" an answer. Acceptance is 
indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has 
been accepted by the original author of the question."